# how to exit exec() like in a function in Python

Tags: python, function, exec, keyword

I'm currently trying to make an self-modifying algorithm in Python.

To do that, i have a string containing an algorithm that i run using the exec(algorithm) function inside another funciton.

the algorithm that i want to run looks like this :

```
   if (a):
       do_something()
       return
   if (b):
       do_something_else()
       return
   ...
```

the problem is that "exec()" does not act like a function and so the "return" won't work as such.

Of course, it works when i modify the algorithm string into :

```
def function ():

  if (a):
        do_something()
        return
  if (b):
        do_something_else()
        return
    ...

function()
```

But what i want is the keyword that replace "return" in exec().
The keyword that only exits the exec() (not the whole program), if it exists

Comment: Use `if/elif/.../else:` to put each alternative in its own block.

Comment: Refactor. `exec` is a tool of last resort, not a building block for ordinary code. This is almost certainly an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: I believe this is not an XY problem. I'm trying to make a Machine Learning program that uses python code instead of neural network. The exec function is the key of the whole program to test how good a randomly generated program perform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `sys.exit()` function to exit from within the `exec()` function without terminating the entire program. You just need to catch the `SystemExit` exception that `sys.exit()` raises and handle it appropriately.

```
import sys

def run_algorithm(algorithm):
    try:
        exec(algorithm)
    except SystemExit:
        pass

algorithm = '''
if a:
    print("a is true")
    sys.exit()
if b:
    print("b is true")
    sys.exit()
'''

run_algorithm(algorithm)
```

Comment: this works very well, thanks a lot !

Comment: you can just `raise` any error